# Can this code be pulled out into a separate method?

Tags: c#, .net

Can the whole **try-catch block** shown below be pulled out into a method?

My boss asked me to do it but I feel like I'm missing something because I don't think it can be pulled out (without too much complexity, because of the `return Ok(response);` line in it). I don't want to say no to him without being sure.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("endpoint123")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Endpoint123(Data data)
{
    ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject
    {
        Success = false,
        ErrorMessage = "",
        UserAdded = false
    };

    try
    {
        var e = await Request111(data); // this can throw exception
        if (e.result != -1)
        {   
            var success = await Request222(data); // this can throw exception
            if (!success)
            {
                response.ErrorMessage += "errorMessage123";
                // _loggingService is a global variable
                _loggingService.Log(LogLevel.Error, Priority.High, "Error happened");
                return Ok(response); // <-- Notice this returns ok response
            }
        }
        response.Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.ErrorMessage += ex.Message;
        _loggingService.Log(LogLevel.Error, Priority.High, "Error happened");
        response.Success = false;
    }
    
    response.UserAdded = true;
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Comment: If you're in Visual Studio, highlight the lines you want to extract, hit Ctrl+period, and see if there is an "extract to method" option.

Comment: It does not give me anything. I tried right-click + "Quick Actions and Refactorings" as well.

Comment: "Boss asked (...)" did he provide any rationale? Or it's just to test you?

Comment: You'll have to make some changes to it, but sure, it can be a separate method.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - No, its just a comment on my PR. I don't think it's a test, but I don't wanna come off stupid by giving him the wrong answer.

Comment: @devlincarnate - Will it be too complex? If yes, I can say no to him.

Comment: It can't easily be refactored the way the method is now, but that's honestly more of an encouragement to refactor it so `response` isn't used in such tangled ways -- creating a new `Response` for each branch seems much cleaner. Extracting the method would be of little actual use afterwards, since it contains the bulk of the logic.

Comment: @bigShaq Just as a sidenote: You can give yourself the answer by just writing integration tests for this API call. If you have them you can simply try it out without losing or destroying any logic.

Comment: I think your question would better fit to CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be done?
Sure.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("endpoint123")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Endpoint123(Data data)
{
    var response = await Logic(data);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Implementation of Logic() is not overly difficult.
In a real API, I'm not sure it makes sense to return every result as 200 OK but that choice was already made.
Note that to extract this, the Logic() method always returns a `Task<ResponseObject>`.

Also if you only wanted to pull out the try, that is easy if you just return the ResponseObject from your method and then wrap it with Ok() at the call site.

Comment: Is `return OK(await Logic(data))` simpler?

Comment: Yes, if you like that more, go for it.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster - There's a `response.UserAdded = true;` statement in the end in ^my code. That changes things because I am also returning from a previous spot in the try-catch block.

Comment: That does not change the refactoring. Essentially, the logic method is the same as your method above, just with the OK() stripped. Still works with that added property.
Still, this is very good advice: "creating a new Response for each branch seems much cleaner."

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster - in the case that `return Ok(response);` is executed, `response.UserAdded` will remain false (please see near the last statement in my code).